# JavaScript variable visibility in handler

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a little bit confused on how this works, let me post you an example code:

```
someClass = function() {
    this.a = 10;

    this.Foo = function() {
        console.log(this.a); // will output "10"
        setTimeout(this.Bar, 1);
    }

    this.Bar = function() {
        console.log(this.a); // undefined
    }
}
var instance = new someClass();
instance.Foo();
```

My understanding is that this.a is not visible in function Bar if it is called from setTimeout (or some other "handler" type of thing.) 
What is the common/correct way of solving that?

(I am trying this in Node.js btw)

Thank you.

Comment: `this` is confusing in javascript. When you call from the `setTimeout` function the context gets switched. See the thread [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword) for help

Comment: Thank you, I'll do some reading! :)

Answer (score 2):

When passing the function *this.Bar* as an argument to another function, you need to **bind** *this.Bar* to the context you'd like it to be executed with.

If you're using a JS library like jQuery or Underscore.js they already come with that functionality:

```
setTimeout(_.bind(this.Bar, this), 1);
```

Here's a simple implementation of a **bind** function:

```
var bind = function(scope, fn) {
  return function() {
    return fn.apply(scope, arguments);
  };
}
```

**Update**:

As @generalhenry pointed out, node.js already comes with a *bind* function in (*Function.prototype.bind*), so you can do this without adding a custom *bind* function nor an external library:

```
setTimeout(this.Bar.bind(this), 1);
```

Comment: Node.js has Function.prototype.bind, why confuse things with a library or custom implimentation?

Comment: @generalhenry: my answer was a general JS answer.. I mentioned jQuery and Underscore.js as examples, but if node.js already comes with it, then of course you should use that ;)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the scope (`this`) is lost when you pass a function to `setTimeout`.

Here's the easiest way to fix it, store `this` as a reference through a closure and use that instead.

```
// This uses _me_ everywhere for consistency, but the only place that really needs it 
// is within the Bar method. But consistency in this case makes your code more change-
// proof, say if someone calls setTimeout(instance.Foo, 1)
someClass = function() {

    var me = this;
    me.a = 10;

    me.Foo = function() {
        console.log(me.a); // will output "10"
        // setTimeout will cause me.Bar to be called with window as the context
        setTimeout(me.Bar, 1);
    }

    me.Bar = function() {
        // so we avoid using _this_ in here
        console.log(me.a); // 10
    }
}
```

A slightly more elegant way is to use [Function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
someClass = function() {
    this.a = 10;

    this.Foo = function() {
        console.log(this.a); // will output "10"
        // the bind call will force it to use the first argument as `this`
        setTimeout(this.Bar.bind(this), 1);
    }

    this.Bar = function() {
        console.log(this.a); // undefined
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand you're using `me` everywhere for consistency, but it's worth noting that, in this example, the only place where it's strictly necessary is inde `Bar`.

Comment: @bfavaretto Yes, I do tend to choose between one or the other for clarity/consistency, what if you end up calling one of the other functions on a timeout? Or assign them to a different object?